# Validating messages before submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation

I'm making a html5 application which require all fields to be filled in before the submit button can be clicked.
What I want to do now is give an alert if a textbox is not filled in, the problem is that my submit button is disabled until all fields are filled in, so I can't really add an alert to that button.
Any idea's on how to solve this?
I want it so that after filling in the final textbox the submit button becomes available without first having to click on it.
Note that the 'required' does not work.

I have the following code:

**HTML:**

```
<form id="winForm">
<p>
<input type="text" id="name" name="name" required />
</p>
<p>
<input type="text" id="vorname" name="vorname" required />
</p>
<p>
<input type="text" id="email1" name="email1"  required />
<label id="atteken" >@</label>
<input type="text" id="email2" name="email2 "  required />
<textarea  id="fullemail" name="fullemail"></textarea>
</p>
<p>
<input type="text" id="telefon" name="telefon" onclick="generateFullAdress()"  required />
</p>
<p>
<input type="text" id="firma" name="firma"  required />
</p>
<p>
      <input type="submit" id="submitBtn" onclick="sendTheMail()" value=" ">
</button><div id="loading"><img src="images/loadingBar.gif" id="load"></img></div>

</p>
</form>
```

**Jquery/JS**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function generateFullAdress() {

document.getElementById('fullemail').value = 
document.getElementById('email1').value + '@' + 
document.getElementById('email2').value;

}

</script>

<script>

var $input = $('input:text'),
    $register = $('#submitBtn');    
$register.attr('disabled', true);

$input.keyup(function() {
    var trigger = false;
    $input.each(function() {
        if (!$(this).val()) {
            trigger = true;
        }
    });

if(trigger) {
    $register.attr('disabled',true);    
}else {

    $register.removeAttr('disabled');  

}
});
</script>
```

Help would greatly be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: In the first function you are using javascript. As you bind in jquery I'd use in this function, too. I do not know following syntax: $('input:text') but I do know following: $('input[type="text"]'). As far as I know the variable "trigger" exists within the function but not outside of it.

Comment: just use HTML5 validation. you know, input attribs like _required_, _pattern_, type=email, etc... it does everything you asked for without a sinlge line of javascript.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a form as such:

```
<form id="form">
...
</form>
```

You can use the following jQuery code to do something before the form is submitted:

```
$(function() {
    $('#form').submit(function() {
        // DO STUFF
        return true; // return false to cancel form action
    });
});
```

**OR**

perform the samething with the onsubmit event like

```
<form action="youraction" onsubmit="validatefunction" method="post">
```